# Несколько баз данных в Silex

Tags: doctrine2, silex

Необходимо в проекте с silex + doctrine2 разделить соеденения к  БД для записи и чтения. в инете есть способы настроить типа:

```
  $app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'dbs.options' => array (
        'mysql_read' => array(
            'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
            'host'      => 'mysql_read.someplace.tld',
            'dbname'    => 'my_database',
            'user'      => 'my_username',
            'password'  => 'my_password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
        ),
        'mysql_write' => array(
            'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
            'host'      => 'mysql_write.someplace.tld',
            'dbname'    => 'my_database',
            'user'      => 'my_username',
            'password'  => 'my_password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
        ),
    ),
  ));
```

но как приетом работать с использованием ORM не понятно.